# Android Studio and 9-patch error

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

I made a 9 patch image using Android Studio function "create 9-patch file".

Now android studio tells me that there is a "duplicate" resorces error, since I have image.png and image.9.png.

If deleted image.png (after even cleaning and rebulding the project) I get this error:

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you do `Try Invalidate and Caches` ??

Comment: Yes, I did it, but the problem persists

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I face it as well

Comment: I found that one 9-patch file was causing the problems. When I used older copy build succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Remove both, then clean, then paste the desired one

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as suggested, try Invalidating Cache. To do this: Click on *File > Invalidate Cache / Restart*.

If you have a conflicting library in `lib` folder, try removing it and rebuilding project. To do this, you can manually check `lib` folder in your project directory. Do you have a jar? Maybe you have multiple versions of same library in `lib` folder.

Also: you can: click on *File > Project Structure. Select `app` and see your libraries.

And, if your project is really big so that it exceeded the 65K methods dex limit in Android(typically happens if you used too many libraries). You can add `multiDexEnabled` to true in your top level *build.gradle > defaultConfig*

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Optionally, you can increase heap size

```
dexOptions{
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"     // 4GB
}
```